# How to render an array of html code in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i want to push `newUsers` into an array and then display that array , `newUsers` will be an html code with informations and whenever someone enter his informations and click 'Add' an html code will be push into users array  ,but the problem is that 'v-html' is not reading the code probably because when i right the code manually i get different display results check it out : https://codesandbox.io/s/3r3po83rkp

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `v-html` is that you are trying to display the array itself and not the items in it.

Change this:

```
<div class="req"><span v-html="Users"></span></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="req" v-for="(user, index) in Users"><span :key="index" v-html="user"></span></div>
```